# Toggle Startpage and login form in a SPA (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, single-page-application

I would like to define a startpage only with logo and two buttons (SignIn, LogIn). Only when the user click one of these buttons the registerform or loginform will displayed. The startpage has a toggleFunction as "sidebar" in angular material.

startpage:

[image]

form:

[image]

How can I achieve this with angularjs and angular material?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the elements in the start up of the page except two buttons and once you click a button you should hide two buttons and show the specific form.Make sure to keep alignments correctly. You can use this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow